# Split data into train/ test files such that at least one sample is picked for both the files

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a csv file which is read into a dataframe. I split the it into training and test files based on the values of one column.

> Let us say the column is called "category" and it has several category names as column values
>    such as cat1,cat2,cat3 and so on which repeat more than once.

I need to split the files such that each category name comes in both the files at least once.

So far I am able to split the file into two based on ratio. I have tried many options but this is the best one so far.

```
  def executeSplitData(self):
      data = self.readCSV() 
      df = data
      if self.column in data:
         train, test = train_test_split(df, stratify = None, test_size=0.5)
         self.writeTrainFile(train)
         self.writeTestFile(test)
```

I do not fully understand the stratify option in test_train_split. 
Please help. Thanks

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use it according to the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) and couldn't get `stratify` to work.

#### Setup

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
p = np.arange(1, 5.) / np.arange(1, 5.).sum()
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': np.random.choice(('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4'), (1000,), p=p),
                   'x': np.random.rand(1000), 'y': np.random.choice(range(2), (1000,))})


def get_freq(s):
    return s.value_counts() / len(s)

print get_freq(df.category)

cat4    0.400
cat3    0.284
cat2    0.208
cat1    0.108
Name: category, dtype: float64
```

If I try to:

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, stratify=df.category, test_size=.5)
train, test = train_test_split(df, stratify=df.category.values, test_size=.5)
train, test = train_test_split(df, stratify=df.category.values.tolist(), test_size=.5)
```

All returned a:

> TypeError: Invalid parameters passed:

The docs say:

> stratify : array-like or None (default is None)

I can't think why this wouldn't work.

I decided to build a work around:

```
def stratify_train_test(df, stratifyby, *args, **kwargs):
    train, test = pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame()
    gb = df.groupby(stratifyby)
    for k in gb.groups:
        traink, testk = train_test_split(gb.get_group(k), *args, **kwargs)
        train = pd.concat([train, traink])
        test = pd.concat([test, testk])
    return train, test

train, test = stratify_train_test(df, 'category', test_size=.5)
# this also works
# train, test = stratify_train_test(df, df.category, test_size=.5)

print get_freq(train.category)
print len(train)

Name: category, dtype: float64
cat4    0.400
cat3    0.284
cat2    0.208
cat1    0.108
Name: category, dtype: float64
500

print get_freq(test.category)
print len(test)

cat4    0.400
cat3    0.284
cat2    0.208
cat1    0.108
Name: category, dtype: float64
500
```

Comment: Hi piRsquared.. thanks for the help. But I need a bit more info.. each category is added to both the files at the end but the splitting is not happening.

Comment: print test1  category Column2
0         1       A
1         1       A
2         2       B
3         3       C
4         3       C
5         4       D
1         1       A
2         2       B
4         3       C
5         4       D
>>> print train1
   category Column2
0         1       A
1         1       A
2         2       B
3         3       C
4         3       C
5         4       D
0         1       A
3         3       C